# Modify worker_connections on App Engine Flexible for .NET

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I am testing out a .NET websocket server on Google App Engine Flexible.  As the number of concurrent connections to the server increased I started to see connection failures and `4096 worker_connections are not enough` in the logs.  I logged into the box and can see that the `nginx_proxy` container has the following config:

```
events {
  worker_connections 4096;
  multi_accept on;
}
```

Looking through the docs I can see that the PHP Flexible `app.yaml` has a `nginx_conf_override` setting but I do not see anything similar for .NET.  What are my options for increasing this value?

**Update:**

I found the following link that suggests I can request an increase from Google Support.  I have sent a request and will report back here once I hear a response.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38243437

Comment: Have you tried to modify the nginx.conf file? Are you using containers?

Comment: Google App Engine flexible does use containers but I don't have control direct control over the nginx_proxy container without doing some hacks, and even then the changes are only temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I heard back from Google support about this issue:

> Unfortunately, the NGINX configuration is fixed and cannot be changed.

They did give me some help in temporarily increasing the limit though

> Actually, it's possible to change the worker_connections value for one instance SSHing into the VM. Nginx config is located in /tmp/nginx/nginx.conf and you can change it manually on a single VM instance running the following commands.
>   However as soon as the VM leaves the debug mode or the VM get's killed the changes you've made will be lost:

```
sudo su
vi /tmp/nginx/nginx.conf #Make your changes
docker cp /tmp/nginx/nginx.conf nginx_proxy:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
docker exec nginx_proxy nginx -s reload
```

I used these steps to increase my worker count to 51200 for testing purposes and confirmed my service was able to receive more connections.  Unfortunately this won't work for our production release but at least I can run tests while I work out another solution.